# mvn:spring-boot run is not working for Spring Boot Ear package

Tags: spring, spring-boot, package, ear

Have created Spring Boot EAR project

```
parent 
  -- ear
  -- war

Ear
 --war
```

Go to war spring boot project inside parent project and execute `mvn:springboot run` throws following error. If I create individual spring boot war application with no ear package, then `mvn:springboot run` command is working.

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, o
at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:95)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:104)
```

Comment: I have found it myself.

Comment: mvn spring-boot:run